# Inject method from controller to a directive not calling with right variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS, and I'm having a problem with 'injecting' a method to a custom directive as an attribute

```
<div ng-controller="LoLImagesController as lolImgCtrl">
    <ul class="list-inline thumbs">
        <li id="champThumb" class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="championName in lolImgCtrl.keysToShow()">
            <champion-thumbnail champion="lolImgCtrl.imageData.champions[championName]" 
                                champion-image="lolImgCtrl.imageData.images[championName]" 
                                champion-info="lolImgCtrl.infoData.champions[championName].info"
                                method="lolImgCtrl.setChampForModal(championName)">
            </champion-thumbnail>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{lolImgCtrl.champForModal}}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, on the 7th line, I'm trying to place a method in the `method` attribute of the `champion-thumbnail` directive.

**champion-thumbnail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
    <div id="champName">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal"
                ng-click="method({championName: '{{champion.key}}'})">
            info
        </button></br>
        <b>{{champion.name}}</b></br>
        {{champion.title | capitalize}}</br>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: {{championInfo.defense}}0%">
            <span>Defense : {{championInfo.defense}} / 10</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: {{championInfo.magic}}0%">
            <span>Magic : {{championInfo.magic}} / 10</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: {{championInfo.difficulty}}0%">
            <span>Difficulty : {{championInfo.difficulty}} / 10</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: {{championInfo.attack}}0%">
            <span>Attack : {{championInfo.attack}} / 10</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img ng-src="{{championImage}}">
</div>
```

You can see that I try to call the method moved inside the directive in an `ng-click` attribute.

**champion-thumbnail directive definition**

```
app.directive('championThumbnail', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { champion: '=', championImage: '=', championInfo: '=', method: '&' },
        templateUrl: 'champion-thumbnail.html'
    };
});
```

**Method transferred to directive : setChampForModal**

```
this.setChampForModal = function (champ) {
    $log.debug("set " + champ + " for modal");
    this.champForModal = champ;
};
```

### **Actual problem**

When I inspect the button, the html shows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="method({championName: 'Aatrox'})">info</button>
```

But when I click the button, the modal opens, showing the title `{{champion.key}}` instead of the actual value (`Aatrox` in the examples case)

What am I missing here? Of course, my eventual goal is that I'll have the actual value, and I'll wrap the modal with a controller that will show the data I want, but for now, I want it to be under the same controller, but it's still not showing right.

P.S: the function has a `$log.debug` call, which shows `set {{champion.key}} for modal`.

---

EDIT: I'm an absolute beginner at AngularJS, and webdev in general. Any form of tip and\or constructive criticism is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this

```
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="method({championName: '{{champion.key}}'})">`
```

ng-click won't resolve `{{champion.key}}` to it's value but instead will put it as a string.

**try**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-arget="#myModal" ng-click="method({championName: champion.key})">
```

instead

Comment: nothing really happens. Instead of `{{champion.key}}`, it puts out `champion.key`, without the `{{ }}`

Comment: @GioraGuttsait Because you still have `'champion.key'` instead of `champion.key`.

Comment: Hi I made this jsffilde [link](https://jsfiddle.net/anotherdaniel/jkqgqogr/) ... in their it works)